# Unable to install Python cloudstorage module

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 on Dell Laptop.

I'm trying to install the cloudstorage module.
When installing the module with Python2 using sudo, it works, however on importing it fails:

python storage2.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "storage2.py", line 6, in 
    import cloudstorage as gcs
  File "/home/maxim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudstorage/**init**.py", line 56
    def get_driver(driver: DriverName) -> Drivers:

Also, when I try installing this module with Python3 it fails:
https://apaste.info/QKYD

1. Why the import fails and how to fix it?
2. How to install this module in Python3?